# Do badges like Electorate do more harm than good?

Tags: discussion, badges, electorate-badge

I know badges exist to reward and encourage the kind of positive behavior we want in our community; however encouraging users to up-vote 600 times for an award may cause abuse in my opinion. If we are not actually performing an evaluation and carelessly up-voting to get badges, we could be promoting garbage on the site.

About a month ago, I decided to get some Silver or Gold badges to improve my reputation. So I opened up the Badges tab to see how should I proceed. I noticed  the SO suggestion under the silver badges:

> [. . .] You'll need to plan your strategy to get one of these.

So I planned to up-vote 40 question a day to gain Electorate. That seemed easy and I was excited. When I was doing this I was also trying really hard to be fair, but still I might have up-voted carelessly a couple of times because of the high number of questions.

I've got the Electorate badge now, but I don't see much value in my achievement. Even though I tried to up-vote the questions considered *researched, clear and useful*, I know *being awarded* affected my judgement and I think it could do the same to others.

There are many overrated and underrated posts in SO. I've seen up-votes on questions that are obviously a "duplicate", or could've been answered easily by Googling the title, or they were short questions that are easy for everyone to read.

#### My Question

If it's not possible to encourage users to be careful when voting (like via some badges, for example), shouldn't we at least restrict careless voting to increase the credibility of the site?

Comment: If you are trying to get a badge as soon as possible that might cause issues, if you let the badge come when it comes then there should be less issues.

Comment: They don't encourage users to up-vote 600 times, but to vote.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9508/why-arent-people-voting-for-questions

Comment: clearly the solution is to downvote 600 times

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Why did you plan to upvote 40 question per day?  the electorate badge covers upvotes and downvotes as long as they are on questions.

> Vote on 600 questions and 25% or more of total votes are on questions.

If you were just upvoting to get a badge then that is an abuse of the system and you should not do it.  There are plenty of question out there that are bad that you could down vote and flag/vote to close which would get you the badge just as fast and improve the site at the same time.  You also get the added benefit of working towards the Marshall badge for flagging 500 post.

Comment: I didn't know about the down-vote. thanks for your answer.

Comment: Honestly for me "Vote on 600 questions and 25% or more of total votes are on questions." is confusing, I also didn't know it was for downvotes. Maybe someone can make a more clear title for that badge? The title if confusing. If I vote on 600 questions, how is 25% on questions? it is already 100%. What does "vote on 600 questions" imply?

Comment: @GiorgiMoniava It means that 25% of all up/down votes you have cast so far must be on questions in addition to voting on 600 questions. In other words, `if(votesCastOnQuestionsByThisUser() >= max(600, votesCastByThisUser()/4)) awardThisUserABadge("Electorate");`

Answer (score 5):

Encouraging voting is (IMO) mostly a good thing.  If I had to guess, the voting badges were created because:

- The StackExchange model is heavily built upon the voting system, where good posts rise to the top and bad ones sink under the weight of their problems.  Voting is the mechanism that drives this, so it's important to encourage people to keep voting.
- Requiring 600 votes on questions for the electorate gold badge means rapid identification of questions while also retaining a loyal userbase.

Here are some possible downsides to the voting badges:

1. Voting on StackOverflow can be hard.  Once you get past the formatting and presentation of a post, judging its technical merits can be challenging.
2. People can be lazy, and they might try to rush votes by giving hasty judgments in trying to get these badges.  This is an example of your careless voting.

And my counterarguments for these downsides:

1. Voting is hard, but people are better judges of quality than they think.  And with large amounts of data, errant votes can be properly diluted by "correct" ones.
2. This might not actually be as bad as it sounds, since there are a good number of posts (especially questions) that obviously deserve downvotes.  Besides, I'm not convinced this voting badge is one a badge hunter would target first.  It's probably a lot easier to go after edits or consecutive days visited.  And if you're the kind of user who is visiting 100 consecutive days, that's only 6 question votes a day.  And that's few enough to have confidence that the votes aren't careless.

---

TL;DR

I think the voting badges are fine as they are currently defined.  I don't think they create many voting anomalies.  And voting is important to how the site works, so they are doing their job in encouraging good behavior.

Comment: I agree about the affect of large amounts of data. Thanks for your answer.